# How to Add csv file data into multiple Table in SSIS Package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have data in .CSV file and I want to insert that data into multiple Table in SQL SERVER using Single SSIS Package.
I tried Multicast option but not come up with the solution...

if you have any idea how to do this please share the solution.....

Comment: Multicast can work.   Please show us what was wrong with your attempt to use it.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: One other option is insert into a single table from the file and then have SQL code do inserts into the other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Multicast is the way how one does is SSIS. It will work for sure as I am using them in my project while reading from files. It seems you were missing something or a mistake while developing. It will help us if you post the error you got while using multicast.

Please check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ae35ca/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-multi-cast-transformation-in-ssis/) article for more info on multicast

Or else as stated by Brad, you can go for a direct insert into SQL table which acts as a Landing layer and write custom code or a multicast in a separate dataflow task suffices here

Thanks,
Sree